# How can I assign an <img src> from a variable of an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

How can I assign the `<img src>` that is inside some infobox content, if i am pulling the image from a variable.
eg. I have an output of an image to an array of images which are displayed in the 'output' div.

```
$("#output").append("<img src='"+availableImages["nla"]["images"][i]+"-v'>");
```

I want to be able to take just the first image of this, and display it under the "myPic" id:

```
var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
  '<div id="siteNotice">'+
  '</div>'+
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+results[0].formatted_address+'</h1>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p><b>'+results[0].address_components[0].short_name+'</b>, some info text here...sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the Northern</p>'+'<img id="myPic" src="">'+
         '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+'(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
  '</div>'+
  '</div>';
```

I have tried doing this below(after the #output) but I am getting a 'TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null' error.

```
var abcImage="'" + availableImages["nla"]["images"][i] + "-v'";
document.getElementById("#myPic").setAttribute('src',abcImage)
```

How can I fix this!

It seems awefully hard for something that seems relatively simple in principle. I just want to add an image to my InfoWindow!

Comment: I don' think your question has enough context to indicate where the problem is.  What you have described is correct in concept, and "should" work - so there is some problem with the details of the implementation.  Does the generated HTML look as you would expect?

Comment: change `#myPic`  to `myPic` in the getElemByID (unless its `<img id="#myPic"...` everything else looks ok - provided i is set to a number (0)

Comment: Is it just me, or are there some issues with the use of quotes here?

Comment: var abcImage="'" + availableImages["nla"]["images"][0] + "-v'";
$('#myPic').attr('src',abcImage);

Comment: So I fixed the '#' and did a little tidying but I am only getting one marker showing an image, but this isn't even a image just a broken image sign. Would there be any particular reason this is occuring?

Comment: Checking the inspector again, I have a few ' Failure to load resource: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND and the filename.. 
Which is telling me it's trying to find the file locally instead of from the server.